# Сессии автоматически удаляются

Tags: laravel

Я использую Laravel auth, не знаю почему но у меня такая проблема, когда я на сайте активен и делаю что то он иногда делает автоматический logout. Я не могу понять от чего это, потому что нет конкретные случае когда это происходит. Пожалуйста дайте совет.

Comment: `config/session.php` параметр `'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),`

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите настройки вашего **AuthServiceProvider** в директории app/[Policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication).

Политики-это простые классы PHP, которые группируют логику авторизации на основе ресурса, который они разрешают.

Так же проверьте настройки [сессии](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29350564/laravel-automatically-logged-out-after-few-seconds)

Comment: Спасибо, ты мне очень помог, я изменял SESSION_DRIVER=database, и все супер.